# Handling return value from Web Service Call Wrapper

Tags: c#

I created this method below which makes an HTTP call to a 3rd party API.  I just want opinions on if I'm handling this the best way.  If the call fails, I need to return the ExistsInList bool value only if the response is not null.  But in the last return statement, wouldn't I have to essentially do another return selectResponse == null ? false : selectResponse.ExistsInList; to check for null first just like the previous return in the catch?

Just seems redundant the way I'm approaching this and I don't know if I really need to check for null again in the final return but I figure yes, because you can't always rely on the response to give you a valid response even if there were no errors picked up.

```
public static bool UserExistsInList(string email, string listID)
{
    SelectRecipientRequest selectRequest = new SelectRecipientRequest(email, listID);
    SelectRecipientResponse selectResponse = null;

    try
    {
        selectResponse = (SelectRecipientResponse)selectRequest.SendRequest();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return selectResponse == null ? false : selectResponse.ExistsInList;
    }

    return selectResponse.ExistsInList;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Suggestion #1: don't eat exceptions! You have no idea whatsoever what kind of exceptions you're ignoring. You're assuming that any exceptions at that point imply a problem with the third-party API, but that may not be the case.

My suggestion is to at least log the exception and *then* ignore it. Be certain to look at the log during development so you can see what kind of exceptions you're getting. Look at the code in the wrapper to understand which exceptions you might reasonably receive (or rather, which ones mean that something reasonable has happened, like a communication failure).

Then, change this code to catch only the exceptions that imply a problem with that API. The rest should be permitted to propagate, to be handled by code that knows how to handle them, or to be handled by code that will log them properly.

See "[Asked to fix bugs in a program, you find over 100 instances of…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029413/asked-to-fix-bugs-in-a-program-you-find-over-100-instances-of)" for an example of someone who had to clean up from code like this.

Comment: Yes, any exceptions that are not `throw;`en must be logged.

Comment: OK, but I do not want to halt my entire application here if I get an exception in this case because I don't care if I get an exception here...it's irrelevant for this particular method dependent on the business logic / scenario

Comment: I agree with you and Nate...thanks, good rule of thumb to remember.  But we do not want to log exceptions if we don't care about them.  For instance if that second call fails, it's ok, it just means they are not in the suppression list and that's just fine.  We are just doing a quick check to see if one is there and if so do a little cleanup and remove that record.  If it does not exist or the SelectResponse fails, we can simply retry later but it's not critical if it fails because it's merely a check for a record on their end for clean-up purposes.  WE don't need to see a ton of those errors.

Comment: Yea but I'm returning a valid value true/false regardless of eating and not logging the error in this case.  And again, these particular API failures in this method are just an extra check, it's not critical if that second call fails.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: You don't _know_ that you don't care about exceptions there, because you don't know which exceptions you'll get. Among other things, you could get an exception that means, "your application is crashing, your data are corrupted, if you continue, you'll destroy data and lose huge amounts of money; now, what do you want to do about that?". The minimum answer to that question is "log it".

Comment: @coffeeaddict: that second call failing does not mean they're not in the suppression list. It means "something has happened, it could be that they're not in the supppression list, or it could be something else; care to bet your business on which it is?"

Comment: @coffeeaddict: finally, an "API failure" should ideally be indicated by the API throwing one of a small set of documented exceptions. In any case, only a small subset of the set of all exceptions might turn out to be something you'd recognize as an API failure. The rest of them are something you want to log. Consider, what's the worst that can happen? You log lots of exceptions you don't care about. So, that would be a time to use "`catch (ExceptionIDontCareAbout){}`". Until then, you don't know what you do or do not care about!